# Convert PySpark dataframe column type to string and replace the square brackets

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert a PySpark df column type from array to string and also remove the square brackets. This is the schema for the dataframe. columns that needs to be processed is CurrencyCode and TicketAmount

```
>>> plan_queryDF.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publishedDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- plannedCustomerChoiceID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- assortedCustomerChoiceID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CurrencyCode: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- TicketAmount: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- currentPlan: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- originalPlan: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- globalId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PlanJsonData: string (nullable = true)
```

sample data from dataframe

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|          event_type|       publishedDate|plannedCustomerChoiceID|assortedCustomerChoiceID|CurrencyCode|TicketAmount|currentPlan|originalPlan|    globalId|        PlanJsonData|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|PlannedCustomerCh...|2016-08-23T04:46:...|   087d1ff1-5f3a-496...|    2539cc4a-37e5-4f3...|       [GBP]|         [0]|      false|       false|000576015000|{"httpStatus":200...|
|PlannedCustomerCh...|2016-08-23T04:30:...|   0a1af217-d1e8-4ab...|    61bc5fda-0160-484...|       [CNY]|       [329]|       true|       false|000189668017|{"httpStatus":200...|
|PlannedCustomerCh...|2016-08-23T05:49:...|   1028b477-f93e-47f...|    c6d5b761-94f2-454...|       [JPY]|      [3400]|       true|       false|000576058003|{"httpStatus":200...|
```

how can I do it? Currently I am doing a cast to string and then replacing the square braces with regexp_replace. but this approach fails when I process huge amount of data.

Is there any other way I can do it?

This is what I want.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|          event_type|       publishedDate|plannedCustomerChoiceID|assortedCustomerChoiceID|CurrencyCode|TicketAmount|currentPlan|originalPlan|    globalId|        PlanJsonData|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|PlannedCustomerCh...|2016-08-23T04:46:...|   087d1ff1-5f3a-496...|    2539cc4a-37e5-4f3...|       GBP|         0|      false|       false|000576015000|{"httpStatus":200...|
|PlannedCustomerCh...|2016-08-23T04:30:...|   0a1af217-d1e8-4ab...|    61bc5fda-0160-484...|       CNY|       329|       true|       false|000189668017|{"httpStatus":200...|
|PlannedCustomerCh...|2016-08-23T05:49:...|   1028b477-f93e-47f...|    c6d5b761-94f2-454...|       JPY|      3400|       true|       false|000576058003|{"httpStatus":200...|
```

Comment: what is your spark version ? you can try `collect_list("TicketAmount")[0], collect_list("CurrencyCode")[0]`

Comment: running version 1.6.1

Comment: collect_list("TicketAmount")[0] does not work. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'collect_list'

Comment: `plan_queryDF.select("
 event_type, 
 publishedDate, 
 plannedCustomerChoiceID, 
 assortedCustomerChoiceID, 
 collect_list("CurrencyCode")[0], 
 collect_list("TicketAmount")[0], 
 currentPlan, 
 originalPlan, 
 globalId, 
 PlanJsonData
")`

Comment: not working. pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList because: Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array<string> was passed as parameter 1

Comment: plan_queryDF.select('originalPlan', collect_list('CurrencyCode')[0], 'PlanJsonData', 'globalId', 'event_type', 'currentPlan', 'plannedCustomerChoiceID', 'publishedDate', collect_list('TicketAmount')[0], 'assortedCustomerChoiceID')

Comment: I got a workaroud, while quering on the parent dataframe i did a cast to string and then ran the dataframe through a udf.

Comment: I'm about to type it. That must work.

Comment: 'from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    lbracesDeleteUDF = udf(lambda s: s.replace("[", ""), StringType())
    rbracesDeleteUDF = udf(lambda s: s.replace("]", ""), StringType())'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130785/discussion-between-occasional-visitor-and-mrsrinivas).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try [`getItem(0)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem):

```
df \
    .withColumn("CurrencyCode", df["CurrencyCode"].getItem(0).cast("string")) \
    .withColumn("TicketAmount", df["TicketAmount"].getItem(0).cast("string"))
```

The final cast to string is optional.