# DataBricks: Run Transformation on Column of Strings

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm getting a runtime error because I'm trying to pass a vector into a scalar function.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018182/how-to-do-string-transformation-in-pyspark
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-string-to-bytes-in-python
# https://www.educba.com/pyspark-withcolumn/
# https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sql-types-datatype-with-examples
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504371/apply-function-to-all-values-in-array-column-pyspark
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184116/convert-pyspark-dataframe-column-type-to-string-and-replace-the-square-brackets
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def decodeRowKey(a):
    return bytearray.fromhex(a).decode("utf-8")

# BEGIN These lines work as expected and return PL/SQL and Groovy respectively
testDecodeRowKeyFunc = decodeRowKey("504C2F53514C")
testDecodeRowKeyFunc2 = decodeRowKey("47726F6F7679")
# END   These lines work as expected and return PL/SQL and Grovvy respectively

originalDF = sqlContext.table("tiobe_azure_backup")

originalRowKey = col("RowKey")
display(originalDF)

# BEGIN This doesn't work
# decodedColumn = originalRowKey.map(decodeRowKey)
# END   This doesn't work
decodedColumn = decodeRowKey(originalRowKey.cast("string"))

transformedDF = originalDF.withColumn('RowKey2', decodedColumn)
display(transformedDF)
```

If you look at the picture, you will see I'm getting 
**TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not Column**
[image]

How do I run my function decodeRowKey on every single element of the column originalRowKey so I can get a new column which I will name decodedColumn?

decodeRowKey is a transformation function. I want to do something like this pseudo-code: 
newColumnOfStrings = map(decodeRowKey, oldColumnOfStrings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using Python API instead of using native Spark APIs.

You need to use `unhex` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unhex.html)) and cast result to a string, something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unhex

transformedDF = originalDF.withColumn('RowKey2', unhex(col('RowKey')).cast("string"))
```

if your column is a string array, then you need to add the `transform` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html)) into a mix:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unhex, transform

transformedDF = originalDF.withColumn('RowKey2', 
  transform(col('RowKey'), lambda x: unhex(x).cast("string")))
```